# error switching to iframe selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, element

Currently I'm attempting to switch to iframe/fancybox, but i'm getting the following error:

```
line 237, in check_response raise exception_class
(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: missing 'ELEMENT'
```

This is how I'm locating the iframe:

```
_iframe_ = {"by": By.XPATH, "value": "//iframe[@class='fancybox-iframe' and starts-with(@id,'fancybox-frame') and contains(@src,'/reminder/add/relation/')]"}


 def __init__(self, driver):
        super(BasePage, self).__init__()
        self.driver = drive
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(self._iframe_)
```

iframe name is:

```
fancybox-frame1518441842751"
```

html:

```
  <iframe id="fancybox-frame1518443041369" name="fancybox-frame1518443041369" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="auto" src="/reminder/add/relation/58048" kwframeid="1"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML of the `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: check edited post.

Comment: Try `self.driver.switch_to.frame(self._iframe_["value"])`  or `self.driver.switch_to.frame(self._find(self._iframe_))`

Comment: this results in NoSuchFrameException. message: no such frame

Comment: You mught need to implement ExplicitWait in this case, e.g. `expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(self._iframe_["value"])`. Anyway, "no such frame" is another issue

Comment: i saw your edit and it worked opening the frame. however it can't inspect element in it. "Unable to locate element". i have tried implicit and explicit waits. 

How can i know selenium switched to iframe correctly?

Comment: If you use `@id` or `@name` of iframe, then you can be sure that you switched to correct frame... If you cannot find element inside iframe, you might need to apply ExplicitWait again for this element

Comment: still getting the can't find element with implicit or explicit waits.

Comment: @Andersson can you have a look here please??
 still didn't solve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766362/selenium-switch-to-iframe-to-locate-elements?noredirect=1#comment84803945_48766362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the `<iframe>` properly you have to change the `Locator Strategy` as follows :

```
_iframe_ = {"by": By.XPATH, "value": "//iframe[@class='fancybox-iframe' and starts-with(@id,'fancybox-frame') and contains(@src,'/reminder/add/relation/')]"}

 def __init__(self, driver):
    super(BasePage, self).__init__()
    self.driver = driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((self._iframe_)))
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see your reply here. I have updated the initial question.  I tried do it a bit different as I switch to iframe in a method.

Comment: i've changed the status back.  and gave best answer.

Comment: The error i get here is: TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 2):

The `id` and `name` attributes looks dynamic (the number doesn't match in the code and html). You can try to locate by partial `id`/`name`

```
_iframe_ = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "[id*='fancybox-frame']"}
# "[name*='fancybox-frame']"
```

As a side note, `frame()` can receive `id`/`name` as parameter

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame('fancybox-frame1518441842751')
```

Would have worked (except for the dynamic issue of course).

Comment: this is correct. i've made an intentional typo in the selector and after i opened the frame, selenium gave me an error. after the switch statement though selenium seems to not be able to locate element inside the frame.

Comment: No. After the iframe window is open it waits for a few seconds and i get a no such element error back.

Comment: @adbSOeh On what do you get the exception? you should also check you are switching to the correct frame and that there are no nested frames.

Comment: the following error: line 80, in untilraise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: i've also tried an implicit wait and the console gives back no such element after the frame is open.

Comment: @adbSOeh I have no idea what line 80 is. You need to post the code you have tried and the relevant html, preferably as a new question.

Comment: I made a new ticket here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766362/selenium-switch-to-iframe-to-locate-elements